# JS - Backspace Detection Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code which is a basic highlighting system, when I try to catch backspaces, I can't catch them, even when I use onkeydown and keypress.

I am using jQuery to get the events and register the function calls. Here is my code:

```
if (e.charCode == 8 || e.charCode == 46 || e.charCode == 35) {
                if (errCount) {
                    errCount--;
                }
                backLetter(index);
                index--;
            }
```

Comment: did you try with e.keyCode == 8 ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `.which`, as in `e.which == 8`

https://jsfiddle.net/skdreow5/1/

```
var xTriggered = 0;
$( "#target" ).keydown(function( event ) {
  if ( event.which == 13 ) {
   event.preventDefault();
  }
  if ( event.which == 8 ||
      event.which == 46 ||
      event.which == 35 ) {
      console.log("backspaced: " + event.which);   
  }
  xTriggered++;
  var msg = "Handler for .keydown() called " + xTriggered + " time(s).";
  console.log(msg);
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work and it doesn't even show me that backspace was pressed!!

Comment: @AnirudhBalaji Yes it does! At least on my machine in FF. Here, I moved it around: https://jsfiddle.net/skdreow5/2/ Hit Run, then click in the input box and do some typing/backspacing.

Comment: I'm using Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/jabole/1/edit)**

[**Regarding `e.charCode`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/charCode)

> This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not
>   use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every
>   user. There may also be large incompatibilities between
>   implementations and the behavior may change in the future.

Either use `e.which` or `e.keyCode` to trap the backspace. Some browsers support `e.which` and some support `e.keyCode`. As part of jQuery concerned, they have normalized `e.which` in the event object. In case you're using jQuery go with `e.which`.

```
$(function() {
  $("input").keyup(function(e) {
   if(e.keyCode==8) {
     alert("Backspace pressed");
   } 
  });
});
```

Comment: keyCode is deprecated. use event.which. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode

Comment: For your first statement isn't entirely true, backspace just isn't supported for `e.charCode`. What it returns depends on the key pressed. You probably mean for the backspace key.

Comment: @beta0x64 Seems [`e.which` is also deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/which).

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek It's like that for KeyboardEvent but [not for jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/). jQuery standardizes e.which. I'm not sure what to think, honestly.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Check this http://jsbin.com/tefako/1/edit?html,js,output it's returning 0 for e.charCode always :)

Comment: @mohamedrias Because it's only supported for the keypress event.

Comment: You suggest to go with which on query but fails to do that on example where you are using jquery and keyCode.

Comment: Please check : http://jsbin.com/jabole/2/edit and http://jsbin.com/jabole/1/edit two different examples @Bart